# Add processing image to text in UpdatePanel control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel that displays the text, 'Please wait while the files are created...', when the user clicks the button 'Create Files'.  Once the processing is completed, the text is updated to display 'Processing completed'.  This works correctly.

What I want to do is add a processing image to the left of the text to show the user that the application is working.  I have added the image. When I set the 'Visible' attribute to true, it displays as a spinning circle.  What I want to do is display the image only when the text, 'Please wait while the files are created...'.

So initially, I set the image to, Visible-"false".  I thought I could just add a line of code to the javascript that displays the text, 'Please wait..' but it is not displaying.  Below is my code:

JavaScript:

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindButton();
});
function bindButton() {
    $('#<%=btnCreateFiles.ClientID%>').on('click', function () {
        $('#<%=lblCaption.ClientID%>').html('Please wait while the label files are being created...');
    //I thought I could just add this line and the image would at least display.
    //But it does not display.  I have also tried setting it to 'visible' and that
    //doesn't work either.   
    // document.getElementById("<%=imgProcessing.ClientID%>").style.display='inline-block';
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProgressUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate> 
 <asp:Image ID="imgProcessing" runat="server" CssClass="floatleft" ImageUrl="~/Images/updateProgress.gif" Visible="false" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblCaption" runat="server" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Red" Visible="true"></asp:Label>            
  <asp:Button ID="btnCreateFiles" runat="server" Text="Create Labels Files" Width="206px" CssClass="label" Height="37px" OnClick="btnCreateFiles_Click" style="float: right"/>                               
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the Code Behind that is in the Click event:

```
 protected void btnCreateFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tstrIssueMonth = string.Empty;
        string tstrFolderPath = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(string),  "bindButton", "bindButton();", true);

//do processing here
            ProgressUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lblCaption);
            ProgressUpdatePanel.Update();
            lblCaption.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblCaption.Text = "Processing completed...files have been created.";
        }
}
```

So, I need to be able to show the processing image when the text, 'Please wait...' is shown and when the text 'Processing completed...' is shown the image is not visible.
How do I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: You may want to look into UpdateProgress control(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821(v=vs.100).aspx) it automates displaying progress for UpdatePanel

Comment: I read up on UpdateProgress when I was trying to implement the text updates. But all I want to do is add an image to the text. Can't I somehow add code to the javascript that will display the image?

Comment: Then just add it directly to html, don't hard code it into ASPX markup: `$('#<%=lblCaption.ClientID%>').html('<img src="imageToDisplay.jpg" /> Please wait while the label files are being created...');`

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you :)